# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 drawable

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I get this runtime error

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

at line 38 of my class: (  `Drawable res = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);`)

```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.breed, null);
        Breed breed = breeds.get(position);
        String breedName = breed.getNameString(context);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.breedNameText)).setText(breedName);
        String uri = "drawable/" + breedName.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
        int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.breedImage);
        Drawable res = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource); // error occurs here
        image.setImageDrawable(res);
        return view;
   }

}
```

I need to change it but I also need to change it to something that will change my pictures to the appropriate one as I am using this to drag different pictures for different groups. can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
String uri = "drawable/" + breedName.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
```

With

```
int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(breedName.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_"), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

Note:

```
1. getIdentifier returns 0 if no such resource was found. (0 is not a valid resource ID.)
2. Also check in your R.java whether there is a drawable with the given breedName.
```

For more detail refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).